# How to read a yaml or json file in GitHub actions to pass application tag dynamically?

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to make my GitHub actions generic, i have a properties file in the format of yaml, just like the values.yaml in helm, i would like to pass the docker image tag of a particular version of the API that is being modified.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of that YAML file in your question along with the tag you want to pass. Apparently, it seems like you can use [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) to accomplish this. However, with a proper example, it'll be more clear.